# Expo image picker can't request permissions and launch camera in a single click

Tags: react-native, permissions, expo, ios-camera, expo-image-picker

I am using expo image picker with a react native app on ios to take an image. When a user launches the app for the first time and clicks my "take image" button it prompts them for permission to use the camera. I would like for my function to launch the camera after they have granted permission, but instead they have to click "take image" again to get the camera to launch. Is there a way to accomplish this without requiring a second click from the user? I tried to call the takeImage function again if permissions is granted, but that causes an infinite loop where permissions.status is undetermined, but requestPermission is granted.

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
const [permissions, requestPermission] = ImagePicker.useCameraPermissions(); 
const takeImage = async () => {
    if (permissions.status == 'granted') {
      let data = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      });
      if (!data.canceled) {
        // Do something with the image
      }
    } else {
      requestPermission().then((res) => {
        // console.log(res['granted']);
        if (res['granted']) {
          console.log('permission granted, launching camera again');
          // Calling takeImage() here throws us into an infinite loop where permissions.status is undetermined, but requestPermission() is granted
          // takeImage();
        }
      });
    }
  };
```